# Inefficient if/then loop in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'd like to clean up the results of a SQL query that is always run manually from with Management Studio. But my if/then loop is taking much longer than the individual elements.

Currently, this Select statement runs instantly (less than 1 second) and is usually empty:

```
Select * from A join B on A.id=B.id
```

Instead of an empty result set, I wanted to display a message if there were no results (this is part of a larger multi-part query so the clarity would help). I changed it to this:

```
If (Select count(*) from A join B on A.id=B.id)>0
begin
    Select * from A join B on A.id=B.id
end
else
    Select 'No Results'
```

Since both Select statements in there run near instantly (I checked), I expect this entire snippet to run in the same amount of time.  Instead, it takes EIGHT seconds.  Why is this taking so much longer and is there a simple way around it?

Comment: What do the query plans look like for running separately and running together? Is the timing repeatable? If taking awhile just sometimes,  could be locking.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance, at the risk of turning this into a never-ending question: Yes, the timing is repeatable and very consistent.  Both tables and the query itself are all run on the same server.  Neither table has unique keys defined or use any special optimization methods (we try to keep the process flexible to handle dirty incoming data).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `if exists`

```
If exists (Select * from A join B on A.id=B.id)
begin
    Select * from A join B on A.id=B.id
end
else
    Select 'No Results'
```

Comment: Bingo, simple and fast.  Thanks.But do you know WHY my query was so slow?

Comment: You were using the result of aggregate function count(*), which will scan the whole table and count the number of rows which will take time, but in case of **if exists** it will break once a record found

Comment: Probably due to yours going through every record to get a final count of the times the condition is met against the exists which will stop checking as soon as it finds the first record that meets the conditions.

Comment: Taking @PowerUser's times at face value, `select * ....` runs in under a second, `select count(*) ...` should also run under a second, because it is not doing any more work the `select *`. Which OP verified. "Since both Select statements in there run near instantly (I checked)" Under a second + under a second is much less then eight seconds to run them both. Yes, `exists` is a better method, but still does not explain the times given by OP.

Comment: Actually, I need to correct my earlier statement.  If run as-is, @Learning's code still takes 8 seconds.  It's only 'instant' if the If statement uses the aggregate function `Select count(*) from....`.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance, I was thinking the same thing but wasn't sure how to rephrase it.  I still don't know where the 8 second delay comes from.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest checking the result count after the query. This has the down side of giving you a second result set in your output, but it has the upside of not querying the data twice.

```
Select * from A join B on A.id=B.id
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 Select 'No Results'
```

Comment: Actually, this could be good for other reasons, i.e. if I need the result AND start another action if it's populated.  I'll make a note of this.